# Solve equation for y=f(x) to plot it

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Is it necessary to solve the equation for y, to plot y as a  function of x?, I tried to solve it using (Solve) but I got nothing!

```
ϵ1 = 1; ϵ2 = 2.25; h = 6.6*10^-16; c = 3*10^8; ϵ0 = 8.85*10^-12; e = 0.4; 
a = 5*10^-3; α = 1/137;
Solve[ϵ1/Sqrt[x^2 - (ϵ1*y^2)/(c^2*h^2)] + ϵ2/Sqrt[x^2 - (ϵ2*y^2)/(c^2*h^2)] 
    + (I*h)/(x*ϵ0)*(4*α*(e/y)/(a/y - I)) == 0, y]
```

Comment: Have you seen `ContourPlot`?

Comment: I may not have waited long enough but `Solve` on my system took too long. I tried `FindInstance` and applied to `x` and `y`. It appears complex numbers are involved in the solution. Plotting `y` as a function of `x` when they are complex is challenging.

Answer (score 2):

The expression to be solved is complex, so we first determine the real and imaginary part. Now we try to find a solution for both parts. Before that we increase the precision.

```
 eqn = SetPrecision[ϵ1/Sqrt[x^2 - (ϵ1*y^2)/(c^2*h^2)]
 + ϵ2/Sqrt[x^2 - (ϵ2*y^2)/(c^2*h^2)] + (I*h)/(x*ϵ0)*(4*α*(e/y)/(a/y - I)), 50];

{re, im} = ComplexExpand@ReIm@eqn;
FindInstance[re == 0, {x, y}, Reals, 1]
{}

FindInstance[im == 0, {x, y}, Reals, 1]
{{x -> 0.43750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 
  y -> 0.0013313844174624520551450978945477540514890655915713}}

im /. %
{0.*10^-53}
```

There is no solution for the real part, whereas only one solution can be found for the imaginary part. The desired form y = f [x] can not be determined and nothing can be plotted.

```
ContourPlot[re, {x, -1000, 1000}, {y, -1000, 1000}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[im, {x, -1000, 1000}, {y, -1000, 1000}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]